# Why can I not push data to new object after filtering it with forEach?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a an array that contain another array, which contains a name and a data.
I would like to to create a second object that contains items from the array where the date is less than the current date.

So I did the following:

```
  data() {
    return {
      currentDate: moment().locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      currentReservations: [],
      reservations: [
        {
          guests: [
            {
              name: 'John',
              reservationDate: '2023-06-01'
            },
            {
              name: 'Bob',
              reservationDate: '2023-06-30'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sortDates(){
      const active = this.reservations;
      active.forEach(reservation => {
        if(reservation.guests.reservationDate < this.currentDate){
          this.currentReservations.push(reservation)
        }
      })
    }
}
```

If I run this method, it just returns an empty array, even if there are dates that are less the current date.

I can get it to work if I use v-for, but I need to do a forEach, because I will need to return the filtered data in a bootstrap table like so:

```
<b-table striped hover :items="currentReservations"></b-table>
```

Comment: `sortDates` doesn't return anything. Can you demonstrate how you're trying to use this object?

Comment: I think you are trying to push data in currentReservation,
you can modify  your sortDates like below
`sortDates() {
  const active = this.reservations;
  active.forEach(reservation => {
    reservation.guests.forEach(guest => { // Iterate over guests array
      if (guest.reservationDate < this.currentDate) {
        this.currentReservations.push(reservation);
      }
    });
  });
}`

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are using an assignment operator (=) instead of a property name and value pair (:) inside the data return object. This is because the data return object is a JSON object, which follows a specific syntax. To fix this, you need to change your line of code from

currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

to

currentDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

This will make your code valid and run as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a computed:

```
  computed: {
    currentReservations() {
      return this.reservations.filter((reservation) => reservation.guests.reservationDate < this.currentDate);
    },
  },
```